# How to update variables of other classes using action listener

Tags: java, swing, variables, awt, actionlistener

I'm trying to use an action listener to update a value of 'Balance' in an ATM sort of program. I'm currently stuck on ways to update the original value of Balance once changes have been made. Many different action listeners could change this value too eg. withdraw £5, deposit £X etc.

This is where I have added the buttons to the interface:

```
protected void buildGUI(){
    int balance = 10; //sets the initial balance of the user
...
JButton withdraw5 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00a35");
    Withdraw5Listener w5 = new Withdraw5Listener(screen,balance);
    withdraw5.addActionListener(w5);

    JButton withdraw10 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00a310");
    Withdraw10Listener w10 = new Withdraw10Listener(screen,balance);
    withdraw10.addActionListener(w10);

    JButton withdraw20 = new JButton("Withdraw \u00a320");
    Withdraw20Listener w20 = new Withdraw20Listener(screen,balance);
    withdraw20.addActionListener(w20);

    //adds action listener to the deposit button
    JButton deposit = new JButton("Deposit");
    DepositListener dl = new DepositListener(screen, inputLabel,balance, withdraw5, withdraw10, withdraw20);
    deposit.addActionListener(dl);
```

And here is where I've made the action listener classes (They are pretty much duplicates of each other save some minor details so here is just one of them).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Withdraw5Listener implements ActionListener {

private int balance;
private JTextArea screen;

public Withdraw5Listener(JTextArea display, int money){
    balance = money;
    screen = display;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (balance > 5){
        balance = balance - 5;
        screen.setText("You have withdrawn \u00a35 \n" + "Your balance is " + balance);
        System.out.println("Withdrawn \u00a35");
    }
}
}
```

Of course, each of these classes would just use the original balance value of 10 so how would I get it to change the original value?

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Haha whoops thanks!

Comment: Just as you're doing with the text area that you want to update, also pass the text field or whatever object that you want to read the balance from. Everything would be much simpler if the listener was an inner class of the GUI class.

Comment: That is very true... Inner classes can use the variables of the outer class can't they?

Comment: Yes, that's why it would make everything much simpler.